# Finding exact text in <li> with the inputted value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of words

```
<li>name</li>
<li>myname</li>
<li>yourname</li>
```

and i have an input box `input type="text" value="name" id="the_value"` with the value of `"name"` and a submit button with the id `"submit_me"`. What is the exact code for this.

```
$("#submit_me").click(function(){
    var ans = $("#the_value").val();
    var list_item = //list items that will match the inputted value;

    if(ans == list_item){
        list_item.css("color","blue");
    }

    else{
        alert("No word found on list item");
    }
})
```

for the output, the list item with the value `"name"` will be in color blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the objects using `.each()` and compare contents using `.text()`:

```
$("#submit_me").click(function(){

var found = false;
var ans = $("#the_value").val()
$("#list_items li").each( function(){
    if( $(this).text() == ans ){
        $(this).css("color","blue");
        found = true;
    }
});
if ( found == false ){
    alert("No word found on list item");
}

});
```

Expects HTML like:

```
<ul id="list_items">
<li>name</li>
<li>myname</li>
<li>yourname</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="the_value" id="the_value" />
<button id="submit_me">Submit</button>
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/29ee12dj/

Comment: Thank you so much this solves my problem. I was thinking of each too but not so sure of how to do it. defines that i'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Use .contains() if you don't want an exact match.

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Get the value from the input. Select the list items using contains.

If you need an exact match, pseudo code:

```
$('li').filter(() => $(this).text('THE EXACT TEXT'))
```

Comment: contains selects all in the list item that contains "name" not with exact value only. what i want is the exact value only.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each `li` using `each()` and then change the color if the desired text is found.

```js
$("#submit_me").click(function() {
  var ans = $("#the_value").val(),
    list_item;

  $('li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == ans) {
      list_item = $(this);
    }
  });

  if (list_item) {
    list_item.css("color", "blue");
  } else {
    alert("No word found on list item");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>name</li>
    <li>myname</li>
    <li>yourname</li>
</ul>

<input type="text" value="name" id="the_value">
<input type="button" id="submit_me" value="Click"/>
```